# Props not propagating to children

Tags: react-native, state, react-props

I'm working on adding swipe to remove functionality to an app we are developing. For reasons we are not using an external library to handle this, so I am writing it myself.

In my project I have a container where I keep state. I use `setState` to update the state, and am passing state down to this child component as a prop. In the component below, `componentWillReceiveProps` is called with the correct value updates when they happen, but the child component of this is not receiving updates to its props. If this doesn't make enough sense or you need to see more code let me know. I've only included the parts of code that I feel are relevant since this is a private project.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.renderWishlistRow = this.renderWishlistRow.bind(this);
  }

  renderWishlistRow(product) {
    return (
      <WishlistRow
        item={product}
        onItemPress={this.props.onItemPress}
        onRemoveAction={this.props.onRemoveAction}
        shouldCloseRemoveButton={this.props.shouldCloseRemoveButton}
        onScrollAction={this.props.onScrollAction}
        itemPressed={this.props.itemPressed}
        onEndScroll={this.props.onEndScroll}
      />
    );
  }
```

Then, inside the render function:

```
return (
  <KeyboardAwareListView
    dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderWishlistRow}
    renderSeparator={renderCardDividerAsSeparator}
    onScrollBeginDrag={this.props.onScrollAction}
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
    onScrollEndDrag={this.props.onEndScroll}
  />
);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:
I am setting state in the parent component with this code:

```
this.setState({
  shouldCloseRemoveButton: true,
});
```

I didn't originally include it because `componentWillReceiveProps` is being called with the correct state changes from the parent component.

EDIT 2: 
My App Hierarchy for this part of the app is as follows:

```
WishlistContainer: contains the setState calls and passes as a prop: shouldCloseRemoveButton={this.state.shouldCloseRemoveButton}
    Wishlist: passes props to its child WishlistRow: shouldCloseRemoveButton={this.props.shouldCloseRemoveButton}
        WishlistRow: Continues to pass the props down as above, but componentWillReceiveProps is not called here, props are not updating at this level.
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setState`? And please post the relevant code.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi See edits, but I didn't include that piece of code because the state changes from the parent component - where setState is being called - are propagating to the first child component, just not any further.

Comment: But if `KeyboardAwareListView` is your parent then `shouldCloseRemoveButton` is not sent as props to its child.

Comment: KeyboardAwareListView is a child of the parent where setState is called. And props are sent to the child that requires it, in the renderWishListRow - which is the method that KeyboardAwareListView calls to render an individual row. Also, as a side note, I'm not trying to argue, just explain my understanding of how these components work and trying to learn anything I need to learn. Thanks for your quick responses.

Comment: Also, @NanduKalidindi, I tried spreading the props into the KeyboardAwareListView {...this.props} with the same result.

Comment: I still am a little confused as to how your hierarchy could be like. Could you please write down skeletons of the components something like `class Parent extends { render{ return (<Child />) } }` `class Child extends { relevant code }`?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi will do tomorrow when I get back to my computer. Thanks for taking time to help.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi, did my update clarify things for you or do you still have questions about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to mark this as answered, because I want a real answer and what I did to work around this is not good enough for me.

That being said, my workaround was to move the piece of state I was trying to propagate into `react-redux`. Setting the redux state to contain what I needed using `mapDispatchToProps`, and then connecting the components that actually needed the state down the line using `mapStateToProps`, allows the components to receive the notifications they need to do their thing.

Again, I am not choosing this as the answer - even though it is what I did to solve the problem - because something else fishy is going on somewhere and I would like to see if anyone knows why things didn't work as they were.

---

EDIT

---

I've run into this issue other times since this originally happened. There is a prop that exists on the Flatlist - This is not the original component I used in the question, but the original component is deprecated now and the Flatlist has the, about to be mentioned, prop for this scenario - called `extraData`. This particular prop is also watched to help the Flatlist determine if it should rerender itself.

Since the ListView has become deprecated, I feel that using a Flatlist and making sure you pass in an `extraData` prop - assuming you have a different prop that will change with your list data changes - is an acceptable answer to this problem.